# casting dictionary in kdb

Tags: casting, kdb

I want to cast dictionary and log it.

```
dict:(enlist`code)!(enlist`B10005)
```

when I do

```
type value dict / 11h
```

but the key looks like ,code

when I do

```
type string value dict / 0h
```

I am not sure why.

I want to concatenate with strings and log it. So it will be something like:

```
"The constraint is ",string key dict
```

But it did not work. The constraint will be like each letter for each line. How I can cast the dictionary so I can concatenate and log it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qs-plain-text for logging arbitrary kdb+ datatypes.

```
q)show dict:`key1`key2!`value1`value2
key1| value1
key2| value2
q).Q.s dict
"key1| value1\nkey2| value2\n"
```

Comment: Yes. And .Q.s1 might be even nicer!

Comment: agreed! couldn't find any documentation for .Q.s1 on code.kx - apart from : −3!x  - returns the string representation of x. Strictly this is .Q.s1, but it's better to use .Q.s. -> .Q.s1 prints much prettier tables/dicts.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things are going on here.

- `dict` has one key/value pair only but this fact doesn't affect how `key` and `value` behave: they return **all** keys and values. This is why `type value dict` is `11h` which is **a list of** symbols. For exact same reason `key dict` is `` ,`code `` where comma means `enlist`: `key dict` is **a list** of symbols which *(in your particular example)* happens to have just one symbol `` `code ``.
- `string` applied to a list of symbols converts every element of that list to a string and returns **a list of** strings
- a string in q is a simple list of characters (see http://code.kx.com/wiki/Tutorials/Lists for more on simple and mixed lists)
- when you join a simple list of characters `"The constraint is "` with a list of strings, i.e. a list of lists of characters a result cannot be represented as a simple list anymore and becomes a generic list. This is why q converts `"The constraint is "` (simple list) to ("T";"h";"e",...) (generic list) before joining and you q starts displaying each character on a separate line.

I hope you understand now what's happening. Depending on your needs you can fix your code like this:

```
"The constraint is ",first string key dict / displays the first key

"The constraint is ",", "sv string key dict / displays all keys separated by commas
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks o much. it helps me a lot. but how can I generalize this so I can write into a function when passing a dictionary. When I tried dict2:(enlist`code)!(enlist`B10005`B10006) and I did "The constraint is ",", "sv string value dict.  It does not work

Comment: ```enlist`B10005`B10006` ``` is a list of list of symbols therefore `value dict` is a list of list of list of symbols, that's why the code doesn't work. You can try ```"The constraint is ",", "sv string dict2[`code]```

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking something for nice logging, something like this should help you(and is generic)
iterate through values, and convert to strings

```
s:{$[all 10h=type each x;","sv x;0h~t:type x;.z.s each x;10h~t;x;"," sv $[t<0;enlist@;(::)]string x]}/
```

string manipulation

```
fs:{((,)string[count x]," keys were passed")," " sv/:("Key:";"and the values for it were:"),'/:flip (string key@;value)@\:s each x}
```

examples

```
d:((,)`a)!(,)`a

d2:`a`b!("he";"lo")

d3:`a`b!((10 20);("he";"sss";"ssss"))
```

results and execution

```
fs each (d;d2;d3)
```

you can tailor obviously to your exact needs - this is not tested for complex dict values